# Subfile with \includegraphics not working in the mainfile

Tags: graphics, pdftex, subfiles

I have a problem trying to get my maindocument to compile a subdocument, with an included figure.

I have the following file-structure setup:

```
 mainfile.tex
  /chap
   /chapter1
    / ch1.tex
      /fig
        image.pdf
```

And so my mainfile.tex document has the following preamble:

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,final]{memoir}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[english]{babel}
 \usepackage{subfiles}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
    \graphicspath{{./chap/chapter1/fig/}}
 %
 %    end preamble
 %
 \begin{document}
 \subfile{./chap/chapter1/ch1}
 \end{document}
```

And in my subfile.tex I have the following setup:

```
\documentclass[../../main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\chapter{ch1}
\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{./fig/image}
\end{document}
```

Now, when I compile the subfile.tex, the image is rendered nice and fine, but when I try to compile, the mainfile.tex, i get the following error from LaTeX:

> LaTeX Error: File '.fig/image' not found

The image in question is a pdf-file which I have stored in a subdirectory inside the directory where the subfile.tex is located, as should be clear from the above structure. I really can't see where it goes wrong? Is it something to do with the order in which the packages are loaded or is it something else entirely?

I really don't get why the above code does not work as intended?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

I solved it myself by providing the graphicspath arguments with both the paths relative to the subfile and from the mainfile as so:

```
 \graphicspath{{chap/chapter1/fig/}{fig/}}
```

This way, both the subfile and the mainfile is able to find the correct folder for the figures.

Comment: Genius! It's a workaround, but it works.

Comment: For further clarification, in subfile.tex, the new command is `\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{image}`